# Delphi 7 Intermittently unable to debug - access violation in BORdbk70.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

At seemingly random intervals, I encounter the following error when attempting to debug programs in Delphi 7:

[image: Delphi Error]

The only way get rid of this error is to close and reopen Delphi and even when I do this I normally see the error again fairly quickly. Restarting my computer can sometimes be useful in stopping the problem from appearing for a while.

To be clear, I am able to compile my project, it's only when I attempt to debug that I have this problem. This seems to be the DLL responsible for debugging, which makes sense.

Delphi is running within a Windows XP SP3 Environment.

Comment: This is a known problem - see : http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11751   It is resolved in Delphi 2006.

Comment: I found this when I was researching the problem. Is it confirmed that reverting back to Windows XP SP1 will resolve the problem? Migration from Delphi 7 is not currently an option for us.

Comment: Don't know.  All I know about the issue is what's on the QC.  One comment there notes *I have found that unchecking both Autosave options 'Editor files' and 'Project desktop' in the Tools/Environment Options/Preferences tab fixes the problem. *  -- maybe that will help?  I think reverting to XP SP1 would be a terrible thing to have to do.  It would probably cause more grief than anything.

Comment: The Autosave options make no difference. That makes me even more hesitant to revert to XP SP1 since it could just be speculation. You're right that it would cause a lot of grief as well.

Comment: You just have to suck it up

Answer (score -1):

insert delphi installer cd, run install and chose repair.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @LPs Of course this is an answer. It may not be a correct answer, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, next oje is ctrl-alt-del and try to restart yoir pc. Call center style.... This answer must be a comment: definitely.

Comment: @LPs Not every issue is nicely solvable, because bugs are everywhere. Repairing the installation is a perfectly valid answer attempt. Updating the software would be another one in the same vein. Restarting the PC or calling the call center are indeed suggestions that do not answer the question. There is always a line somewhere.